# Series of Basic Google Sheet functions combined

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

So I am new to Google Sheets. I am making an inspection report for a small company using Sheets. I would like to add a button to the bottom of the sheet which does the following script:

1. Duplicate original sheet
2. Rename sheet to a cell value +today's date. i.e Fred01011980
3. Email the sheet as a PDF to a recipient.
4. Finally clear the inputted values in the original master template sheet.

I have looked up how to do each of these and a few of them are straightforward, but I don't know how to combine them. Can I just add all of the functions individually together without any additional syntax needed? Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just create another function that calls your functions, like this:

```
function doAllStuff() {
  doStuff();
  doMoreStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
function AllinOne() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = "Inspection";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inspection").copyTo(ss);
  var newname = ss.getSheetByName("Inspection").getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var newnamedate = ss.getSheetByName("Inspection").getRange(3, 2).getValue();
  var sheetx = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var thisSheet = sheetx.getName();
  var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()
  var sheetfinal = ss.getSheetByName("Inspection")



  var old = ss.getSheetByName(newname+newnamedate);
  if (old) ss.deleteSheet(old); 
  sheet.setName(newname+newnamedate); //copies the sheet and renames it to "store+date"
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet)

// below is pdf conversion
 var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var sourcesheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('A1:B176');  // range to get - here I get all of columns which i want
var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
var data = sourcesheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(thisSheet); // can give any name.
var sheetnow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetz = sourcesheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
var destrange = sheetz.getRange('A1:B176');
destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId());
var theBlob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(newname+newnamedate);

var folderID = "File_ID"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  

  MailApp.sendEmail("Email","New Manager Inspection: "+newname+newnamedate, "A new Manager Inspection Report has been added to the Drive.");

  ss.getSheetByName(name).getRangeList(["B176","B150:B164","B138:B146","B129:B134","B119:B125","B106:B115","B99:B102","B84:B95","B78:B80","B66:B74","B55:B62","B48:B51","B34:B44","B25:B30","B18:B21","B10:B14","B4:B7","B2","B16","B23","B32","B46","B53","B53","B64","B76","B82","B97","B104","B117","B127","B136","B148","B166"]).clearContent();
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheetfinal);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Report Submitted, Please do NOT Resubmit. Thank You");



}
```